# Apache using full RAM problem

Tags: server, apache, memory

I have a server with these specification:

```
*CPU*
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU D-1520 @ 2.20GHz
Cores : 8
Cache : 6144KB
*RAM*
2x 16384MB
*Hard Disk*
2 x 300 GB
2 x 2000 GB
*Software*
Ubuntu 14.04
Linux 3.14
Apache2 2.4.18
PHP 5.6.33
MariaDB 10.0.31
```

With one WordPress site and suddenly for the past two days Apache server used full RAM.
I'm using cloudflare, I disabled wp-cron, increase memory size up to 60 GB.
And the problem is still exist, any help what should i do?

Comment: Install query monitor plugin and see if there's some super slow queries running

Comment: I very much doubt a single WP request would take up 16/32GB of RAM, are you sure that this isn't an Apache configuration issue? Perhaps ServerFault would be the better place to ask? WP requests usually only take a few MB of RAM, rarely more than 60-100 unless it's a super heavy site in which case WP Cron is unlikely to have anything to do with it, you'd get PHP max memory exceeded fatal errors, not Apache filling up your RAM

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.